# ASP.NET button not running code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I am working with ASP.NET. I have a couple of pages and several ASP.NET Buttons within them. Everything was working fine the other day and now the ASP Buttons are not running the code behind. I have placed Break points in the code so this is how I know they are not running. I have looked around the internet and tried a few things I have found, like cleaning the solution, clearing cache and cookies. I have even added a new button and that won't run the code behind either. It seems to just be the one page that is having the problem with all the buttons on it. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what this may be and how to fix it?

These are the buttons

```
   <asp:button id="b1" runat="server" OnClick="b1_Click1" Text="Goals" OnClientClick="changegoals(); return false;" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
        <asp:button id="b2" runat="server" OnClick="b2_Click"  Text="Habits" OnClientClick="changehabits(); return false;" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
        <asp:button id="b3" runat="server" OnClick="b3_Click" Text="Diary" OnClientClick="changediary(); return false" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
```

Comment: show the code!!!

Comment: Can you show the markup and your code?

Comment: Make sure there are no JS errors that may prevent postbacks

Comment: Please check for page directive having AutoEventWireup attribute

Comment: Instead of a breakpoint, try adding popups just to verify that your button handlers are truly not being executed.

Comment: OnClientClick="changegoals(); return false;" aborts the postback...

Comment: Can you post the javascript functions? Also use a Javascript debugger to check you don't have JS errors that prevent submission.

Comment: I fixed it now just by copying all the markup and code behind into new files and it is working again, tried the same thing earlier and didn't work, but for some reason it did this time. Really confused. Thanks for all your time

Answer (score 0):

Why you return false on client click

```
<asp:button id="b1" runat="server" OnClick="b1_Click1" Text="Goals"     OnClientClick="changegoals(); return false;" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
<asp:button id="b2" runat="server" OnClick="b2_Click"  Text="Habits" OnClientClick="changehabits(); return false;" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
<asp:button id="b3" runat="server" OnClick="b3_Click" Text="Diary" OnClientClick="changediary(); return false" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
```

You have to return true on client click.

```
<asp:button id="b3" runat="server" OnClick="b3_Click" Text="Diary" OnClientClick="changediary(); return true" CssClass="button"></asp:button>
```

Comment: changing it to true doesnt do anything tried that, even tried getting rid of the clientclick all together. But it seems to be every button on the page even when they dont have clientclicks

Comment: And in your page directive AutoEventWireup is also true?Can you show the b1_Click1 code.

Comment: Yer AutoEventWireup is True

Comment: b1_Click1 just changes the text. Something so simple not even working. Like i said the other day everything was working fine and for a reason I can't understand it just all went boom

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the button has the following code:

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by adding OnClick="Button_Click" keyword

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have always programmed in VB and have just recently been writing in C#. Have already come across this irritating behaviour. Adding the OnClick="whatevercode" in the mark-up seems to fix it.